# Haskell - Filter Last Element

Tags: haskell

I want to filter the last element of a list that does not satisfy a property. An example would be

```
smallerOne :: a->Bool 
smallerOne x = x < 1
```

The function filterLast should give

```
filterLast smallerOne [1, -2, -3, -4, 5] 
[1, -2, -3, -4] //Filters the last element that is not smaller than 1
```

Here is my code (I am a beginner so sorry for the bad attempt)

```
filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
filterLast p [] = [] 
filterLast p xs 
    | p (last xs) = filterLast p (init xs) : last xs 
    | otherwise = init xs
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
smallerOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool 
smallerOne x = x < 1 

filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterLast p (x:[]) = if (p x) then x:[] else []
filterLast p (x:xs) = x : filterLast p xs
```

This is the solution to your problem. Now, also some explanation:

> smallerOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool

you must include the class constraint `Ord` and `Num`, because your are trying to ordonate numbers through this `<` comparison operator. You can read more here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101

`filterLast` is implemented through `pattern matching`, Haskell is pretty smart and will enter the branch that will match the given list, so he will enter this branch:

> filterLast p (x:[]) = if (p x) then x:[] else []

only when there is one element left, i.e your `last element`.

You said you are a beginner, I really recommend you this tutorial, http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters, it is pretty cool.

Comment: There's no pattern to cover `filterLast p []`. This removes "the last element in the list *if it* does not satisfy a property" instead of removing "the last element in the list *that* does not satisfy a property".

Comment: Agreed, this produces a different result from the function OP asked for on inputs like `[1,-2,3,-4]`: the function OP was evidently trying to write in the question would return `[1,-2,-4]`, whereas this answer returns `[1,-2,3,-4]`.

Answer (score 5):

The minimal change that will cause `filterLast` to compile is to use `(++)` instead of `(:)`, as in:

```
filterLast p xs 
    | p (last xs) = filterLast p (init xs) ++ [last xs]
```

(Other lines remain the same.) The `(:)` function is specifically for putting a single extra element at the beginning of a list, which is not what you wanted to do here. For `smallerOne`, you may simply change the type signature in the way suggested by the error message, thus:

```
smallerOne :: (Num a, Ord a) => a->Bool
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible implementation of `filterLast`:

```
filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterLast p = go []
  where go chunk xs = case span p xs of
          (left, []) -> left
          (left, (r:right)) -> chunk ++ left ++ go [r] right
```

The idea is to repeatedly use `span` to split the sequence into two parts: a left half that all satisfy the predicate, and then a right half starting with the first element that doesn't satisfy it. If there is no right half, then we can just return the left half untouched. Otherwise, we have to:

1. Save off the first element of the right half as a "candidate" item that will only be included if we can find a later element that doesn't satisfy the predicate
2. Include the previous candidate element, if any, in the result.

This is substantially more efficient for large lists (and especially infinite lists!) than the approach used in your question, with repeated calls to `last` and `init`. But if this is not an important concern for you, then simply applying the fixes suggested in Daniel Wagner's answer will get you a function that you will find easier to understand.

**Edit**: As suggested in the comments, you can fix one corner case (an infinite list of items that all satisfy the predicate) by renaming this function to `filterLast'` and then defining a new `filterLast` that delegates to it:

```
filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterLast p xs = left ++ filterLast' p right
  where (left, right) = span p xs
```

Note that there are still some sequences where this diverges without ever producing output, such as `filterLast (< 1) $ 10 : repeat -1`. But I think it's impossible for any implementation to address that, because you never find out whether or not to include the `10` in the output list, since you never find another element greater than 1.

Comment: On a finite list, how this compares to the `reverse` solution? Does the concatenation yields worse performance? Should we pass to difference lists instead?

Comment: Your version doesn't work for `take 5 $ filterLast (< 1) [-1, -2..]`. It's easy to fix that: `filterLast' p xs = case span p xs of { (xs1 , xs2) -> xs1 ++ filterLast p xs2 }`. There is probably a nicer solution, which incorporates this idea into `filterLast`, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Hm, good catch. I don't think `filterLast'` is enough to fix it though, right, because then it just breaks for `10:[-1, -2..]`, doesn't it? On the other hand I guess it's impossible for anything to ever work on that input, since you can't ever find out whether to include 10.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is reverse the list and take elements while they dont satisfy the property. The moment an element satisfies a property, you drop it and take the rest of the list. This translates pretty naturally into haskell code.

```
filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterLast p = reverse . uncurry (++) . dropHeadSnd . span p . reverse
  where
    dropHeadSnd (x, y) = (x, tail' y)
    tail' [] = []
    tail' (x:xs) = xs
```

The (++) reduces the efficiency of your code and while its not the asymptotic efficiency, eliminating the (++) will improve your performance.

```
filterLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterLast p = reverse . helper . reverse
  where
    helper [] = [] 
    helper (x:xs) | p x = xs
                  | otherwise = x:helper xs
```

Both of the above functions use two iterations over the list. However remember with recursion you can get information from both behind and ahead. We use the recursive call to figure out if there are any subsequent elements for which 'p' is satisfied.

```
f :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
f p = snd . helper 
 where
   helper [] = (False, [])
   helper (a:as) | p a && flag = (flag, a:as')
                 | p a = (True, as')
                 | otherwise = (flag, a:as')
          where
           (flag, as') = helper as
```

Comment: The example `f` reverses the sense of `p`. It could also be more productive so that the remainder of an infinite list need not be checked to yield the first of two items that fail to pass the filter.

Comment: `tail' = drop 1`. Also, `dropHeadSnd = fmap (drop 1)` (a bit cryptic, though).

Comment: @Cirdec Reverses the sense of p? What? Your second point makes no sense at all either.

Comment: @user5199947 It is prohibitively expensive to reverse an infinite list. Consider `take 2 . filterLast (< 1) $ repeat 1`: this should surely yield `[1,1]`, but you will try to reverse `repeat 1` and never succeed.

Comment: Reverses the sense of `p` in that `f` removes the last item `x` for which `p x == True` instead of removing the last item for which `p x == False`. `filterLast p = f (not . p)`.

Comment: In `f`, if you return the tuple regardless of the decisions you make and short-cut the flag calculation and whether to include the current item in the list you can produce values by evaluating as little of the list as possible. That's what we mean when we say "more productive". https://gist.github.com/Cedev/c0cbd1ff7e70d0b7e53d